# Jquery .submit() doesnt work IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have the next code:

```
submitAccionesDocs: function (typ) {
        if (typ == "descargazip") {
            var array = $("#accionesDocumentos").attr('action');
            var actionCorrect = array.split("?")[0];
            var actionNew = actionCorrect + "?type=" + typ;
            $("#accionesDocumentos").attr('action', actionNew);
            $("#accionesDocumentos").submit();
            alert("submit");
            $("#accionesDocumentos")[0].reset();
            alert("clean");
            $("#loadingimg").hide();
            $("#loadingdiv").hide();
        }
```

I debbug this with "ALERTS" and my problem is that in the function .submit(), this code does not work in IE8.

Attempt to replace that part by

```
                $("#accionesDocumentos").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                });
```

and it did not work. Any need suggestions.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do the alerts show?

Comment: I'm pretty sure e.preventDefault() doesn't work in IE8 either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of jQuery are you using?  The latest version (2.x) doesn't support IE8 or below.

An alternative, would be to use straight Javascript:

Change:

```
$("#accionesDocumentos").submit();
```

To:

```
document.getElementById("accionesDocumentos").submit();
```

Just a thought, assuming that this element is a form with a valid attributes.